# appium 1.4.16 for android doesn't recognize WEB_VIEW context

Tags: java, android, webview, appium

I have an android activity with webview.

However appium 1.4.16 cannot recognize this context.

My android device is with Android 4.2

`myAndroidDriver.getContextHandles()` ==> return list of size 1

I have read two solutions for that:

1) set

```
setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled = true;
```

2) set selendrium mode

a) What does "selendroid mode" really means?
appium not using UIAutomator? Will this affect other tests I have?

b) I have tried this before, but the code execution fails
when I add:

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Selendroid");

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed. Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /Users/eladb/MyWorkspace/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/aapt dump badging 
ERROR: no dump file specified
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.54 seconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
System info: host: 'eladb-macbookpro.roam.corp.google.com', ip: '100.105.45.192', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.2', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: com.waze.mobileautomation.common.android.MyAndroidDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:160)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:168)
```

Comment: `Set<String> contextNames = myAndroidDriver.getContextHandles(); //Just to make sure it returns a Set <String>`. Could you provide more details about your app and the activity please.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.switchTo().window("WEBVIEW");
```

Where driver is an `AndroidDriver` and your `CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME` is set to `""` (empty)